# How do I unhighlight text if a document hasn’t been updated in 30 days

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have random documents that have a button that allows the end user to unhighlight text based on a particular id. Each document has a class of different dates on them:

`<div class="date">10/09/2019</div>`

Is there a way to automatically unhighlight whatever text is highlighted if a document hasn’t been updated for 30 days for example, and have it stay that way without having to refresh each document and go back to the original state of it being highlighted. Below is my code of what I have so far:

```
<button id="removeClass">Remove highlight</button>

<div class="date">10/09/2019</div>

<p id="para1">This is paragraph 1</p>


<style type="text/css">
.highlight {background:green;}
</style>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $('#para1').addClass('highlight');

        $("#addClass").click(function () {

          $('#para1').addClass('highlight');

        });

        $("#removeClass").click(function () {

          $('#para1').removeClass('highlight');

    $('p').each(function(){
      if(this.id){(this.id = "");}
    });

        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Just a heads up, you're using a mix of quotes and  smart quotes: `“ " ' ‘`

Comment: it’s been corrected. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQueries `.each()` to check each element with the `.date` class and perform an action for it. Inside the parameter function you can access the current `.date` element with `$(this)`.
In your case you need to check if the date in the div is more than 30 days apart from the current date. If that is the case then you remove the `.highlight` class.

Note that to be able to use `parent().find()`  to navigate to the right `p` the date belongs to, your HTML needs to be wrapped in a `div`, like shown.

```
<div>
    <button id="removeClass">Remove highlight</button>
    <div class=“date”>10/09/2019</div>
    <p id=“para1”>test test test test test test test test test test</p>
</div>

$(".date").each(function() {
    var diff = new Date(new Date() - Date.parse($(this)[0].innerText));
    var days = diff/1000/60/60/24;

    if (days > 30) {
        $(this).parent().find("p").removeClass('highlight');
    }
})
```

Comment: It seems to not be working. I created a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dude12go8/jt96qxa8/16/

Comment: the highlight works fine. when the date is changed to say 12/20/2019. it still keeps highlighted when refreshed

Comment: I edited the javascript in the answer, this version is working as intended in jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks Chris. I see it now. I was reading the code incorrectly.